# What is the difference between ${foobar} and $(foobar) in a Makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

In bash scripts, I've learned through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) that accessing vars through `"${foobar}"` is the best practice. In Makefiles, I see sometimes usage of `${foobarr}` and sometimes `$(foobar)`. What's the difference between both and what is best practice in Makefile since I see both mixed in the official documentation?

Comment: What's *Schellcheck*?

Comment: @stephanmg Thank you for pointing out my typo. I was already considering linking shellcheck while writing the question but somehow ignored my thoughts. I will do better next time! :)

Answer (score 2):

Both variants are accepted, and as far as I know all features are available with both, even function calls in GNU Make.

Concerning best practices, I don't remember having seen recommendations one way or the other.  `$(...)` seems to be more common, but I don't remember any issues related to `${...}`.

Note that if you want to pass `$` to the shell for interpretation, probably because you want to expand a shell variable unavailable in the Makefile, you have to double it: `$$`.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no difference between them.  They are treated identically in all ways.  Use whichever you prefer.  Some things to consider:

- A make variable is not a shell variable.  It might be helpful to use `$(...)` when dealing with make variables as a visual reminder you're working with make variables.
- Sometimes when nesting variables and/or functions it can be helpful to use different braces for clarity (although make counts open/close braces and won't get confused).
- When writing a complicated script in a `$(shell ...)` function it can sometimes be useful to use `${shell ...}` to avoid conflicts with special shell capabilities like old-style `case` statements.